# How to implement a generic fetch function that validates the query parameter and json result using zod

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm trying to implement a generic fetch function that abstracts away the validation of the query parameters and the json return using `zod` schemas.
I came up with the following prototype but cannot seem to figure out how to type the zod schema parameter:

```js
import {z} from 'zod';

const zodFetch = async <TQuerySchema, TResponseSchema>(url: string, querySchema: TQuerySchema, query: z.infer<typeof TQuerySchema>, responseSchema: TResponseSchema): Promise<z.infer<typeof TResponseSchema>> => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: querySchema.parse(query),
        }),
    });

    return responseSchema.parse(await response.json());
};


const test = async () => {
    const fooSchema = z.number();
    const barSchema = z.string();

    const response = await zodFetch('https://foobar', fooSchema, 1, barSchema);

    console.log(response);
};

void test();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add generic constraints and remove `typeof` since it's already a type:

```
const zodFetch = async <TQuerySchema extends z.Schema, TResponseSchema extends z.Schema>(url: string, querySchema: TQuerySchema, query: z.infer<TQuerySchema>, responseSchema: TResponseSchema): Promise<z.infer<TResponseSchema>> => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: querySchema.parse(query),
        }),
    });

    return responseSchema.parse(await response.json());
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB4jzW)

Comment: Thank you for helping! I just noticed in a modified version of the Playground example, that actually `querySchema.parse(query)` and `responseSchema.parse(await response.json())` do return a type `any` instead of the inferred schema types. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @doberkofler I am unsure since I don't use Zod.